# Create and save list of certain file type within subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which lists all the .jpg files within a folder and it's subfolders. It then saves them as list.txt within the same folder as the batch file.

```
for /R %%x in (*.jpg) do @echo %%~nx >> List.txt
```

But instead of creating the list.txt in the same folder as the batch file, I'm trying it to create a list.txt in each folder and subfolder, so the list.txt would be saved within the same folder as the .jpg files it's listing.

What it does now:

```
├── Main Folder
│   ├──batch.bat
│   ├──list.txt < All jpg's from all folders listed in here
│   ├── Image Folder
│   │   ├── 1.jpg
│   │   ├── Image Folder 2
│   │   │   ├── 2.jpg
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
├── Main Folder
│   ├──batch.bat
│   ├── Folder
│   │   ├── 1.jpg
│   │   ├── list.txt < A list of all jpg's in folder1
│   │   ├── Folder 2
│   │   │   ├── 2.jpg
│   │   │   ├── list.txt < A list of all jpg's in folder2
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `for /R %%x in (*.jpg) do @echo %%~nx >> %%~dpxList.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By redirecting to file `>> List.txt` you are effectively redirecting to current working dir (the directory where you started the batch file from).

Instead tell it to use the drive/path of the token being `%%~dpx`:

```
for /R %%i in (*.jpg) do @echo %%~ni >> %%~dpiList.txt
```

*Note!!* I changed the token to `%%i` as x is also used as token extension `%%~xi` it is just more readable and looks less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

IF always appending to the list.txt file you either need to first initalize all the `list.txt` files or
use a different approach:

```
@Echo off
For /r /D %%A in (*) do If exist "%%~fA\*.jpg" (
    Dir /B "%%~fA\*.jpg" >"%%~fA\List.txt"
)
```